# Cannot seem to fire DeleteCommand when button is an datagrid. Selected event always fires

Tags: wpf

I have a Wpf Form with a tabControl with 2 tabs "Customers" and CustomerDetail"

First Tab is a list of all Customers populated in a datagrid and delete Button as a dataTemplate on each line of the grid.

Selecting a customer it gets the customer details and moves to the second tab.

This all in MVVM and the delete button is mapped to a DeleteCommand .All good.

My Problem
It cannot seem to distinguish when clicking on the delete button it fires the selected event and goes to the other tab.I dont want it to go to the other tab when pressing delete.

How can I do it?

User selects  row and should go to the other tab.

Row is selected and presses delete button just trigger the delete command.

Hope all clear

Any suggestions?

Comment: I saw the same problem in WindowsLiveMail too... maybe its a bug in WPF event routing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `DoubleClick` event for showing CustomerDetails tab. so, when user click on delete button, they just fire click command of the datagrid and nothing happen...

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Cannot use double click as everywehere in the system they use selected.Any other suggestions

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you can put a panel in your ItemTemplate and try handling click event of that panel instade of list item...